# deserializing XML results in no data for any sequence elements

Tags: c#, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I am going to try my best to keep this post short and concise. I apologize in advance if I need to make a number of edits to add code.

**The problem**

I have a class I am able to serialize into XML correctly. The class sends the XML to a web service that returns a XML response. The XML response is then deserialized into objects for additional processing. I am able to properly deserialize my objects, *providing that the returned XML is not a sequence*

**What I have tried**

I have created my class to look like:

```
[other class declarations here to support XML response]

public class OrderInfoListResponse
{
    public List<OrderInfo> OrderInfo { get; set; }

    public OrderInfoListResponse()
    {
        OrderInfo = new List<OrderInfo>();
    }
}
```

The deserializer looks like:

```
using (Stream respStream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(OrderListResponse));
    orderResp = serializer.Deserialize(respStream) as OrderListResponse;
}
```

If I pass in data that looks like:

```
 <ResponseBody>
    <PageInfo>
       <TotalCount>51</TotalCount>
       <TotalPageCount>6</TotalPageCount>
       <PageSize>10</PageSize>
       <PageIndex>1</PageIndex>
 </PageInfo>
 <RequestID>4546ASDDAS54</RequestID>
 <OrderInfoList>
        <OrderInfo>
            <SellerID>XXXX</SellerID>
            <OrderNumber>111111111</OrderNumber>
            <InvoiceNumber>222222</InvoiceNumber>
            ....
        </OrderInfo>
 <OrderInfoList>
```

I am able to get the PageInfo data and RequestID with no isses, but my resulting object shows

```
OrderInfoList
    OrderInfo count = 0
```

If I display the response as a string I get 51 responses.

**The question**

Why am I not able to deserialize into OrderInfo?

**What I've tried**

I tried the following code, but my count is still 0:

```
using (Stream respStream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    StreamReader readerOK = new StreamReader(respStream);
    string resp = @readerOK.ReadToEnd();
    var myEncoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
    var bytes = myEncoder.GetBytes(resp);
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(OrderListResponse));
    orderResp = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(memoryStream) as OrderListResponse;
 }
```

Setting a breakpoint on myEncoder shows that string resp contains a full XML response, setting a breakpoint after orderResp shows all fields are set, except for the list objects.

I have instantiated my orderResp object via setting it to null at the start of the method. I have also instantiated every instance of an object contained within that class, both with no results.

If I remove all collections (lists, arrays etc ) from the classes, I am able to deserialize the first response in the XML file, subsequent responses are not deserialized and are skipped.

Any other ideas? Anyone?

Comment: Just edited my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was how the class was created.

The original class looked like:

public class OrderListResponseBody
    {

```
    public PageInfo PageInfo { get; set; }  
    public string RequestID { get; set; }  
    public string RequestDate { get; set; } 
    public List<OrderInfoListResponse> OrderInfoList { get; set; }  
}
```

The new class looks like:

```
public class OrderListResponseBody
{

    public PageInfo PageInfo { get; set; }  
    public string RequestID { get; set; }  
    public string RequestDate { get; set; } 
    public List<OrderInfo> OrderInfoList { get; set; }  <!-- notice the change
}
```